# React Native TextInput ellipses truncation

Tags: css, react-native

I have seen a lot of questions related to how to add ellipses to overflown text for the TextInput component but no matter what I add to the styles of the TextInput text always seem to add ellipses to overflown text. It has been requested that the overflown text be hidden:

```
<TextInput
    placeholder='0%'
    value={this.state.cbc}
    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ cbc: text })}
    style={styles.compoundInput}
>

.
.
.
compoundInput: {
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 10,
        height: 40,
        padding: 5,
        minWidth: 55,
        maxWidth: 85,
        marginLeft: 10,
        fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
        fontSize: 14,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    }
.
.
.
```

Is there any way to ensure that overflown text is hidden?

Answer (score 0):

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    gridItem:{
        flex:1,  //it can get as much space as it can get
        margin:15,
        height:150,
        borderRadius:10,
        elevation: 5, 
        overflow:Platform.OS === 'android' && Platform.Version >=21 ? 'hidden'
         : 'visible'

    }
```

I think you can use

overflow: 'hidden'

in the styling component. Or I guess you can also look more in specific platform using Platform API.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code